How to Use SYSTEM::CALL in NSIS Script?
I'm trying to call a function from a DLL in my NSIS script using SYSTEM::CALL. Here's the code I'm working with:
Section loadDll
    StrCpy $0 10
    StrCpy $1 5 
    System::Call "$INSTDIR\NSISRegistryTool::Add(i, i) i(r0, r1).r2"
    MessageBox MB_OK "Return value: $0, $1, $2"
    SetPluginUnload manual
    System::Free 0
SectionEnd

I have confirmed that the Add function is correctly exported from NSISRegistryTool.dll, but $2 is empty after the call.
The function declaration in the DLL is as follows:
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int Add(int a, int b) 
{
    return a + b;
}

Could someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong or how to properly use SYSTEM::CALL to retrieve the return value from the DLL function? Thank you!
I modified the code to look like this, but $2 is still empty.
Section loadDll
    StrCpy $0 7
    StrCpy $1 4 
    System::Call "$INSTDIR\NSISRegistryTool::Add(i $0, i $1) i .r2"
    MessageBox MB_OK "Return value: $0,$1,$2"
    SetPluginUnload manual
    System::Free 0
SectionEnd



From the documentation:

Libraries in the system32 directory can be loaded without a path. All other libraries should be loaded with a quoted full path.

Section loadDll
    StrCpy $0 10
    StrCpy $1 5 
    System::Call '"$INSTDIR\NSISRegistryTool.dll"::Add(i r0, i r1)i.r2'
    MessageBox MB_OK "Return value: $2 from ($0, $1)"
SectionEnd

If your .dll is 32-bit and uses cdecl instead of stdcall, it needs to be System::Call '"$INSTDIR\NSISRegistryTool.dll"::Add(i r0, i r1)i.r2 ?c' instead.

Thank you; your code works, but there were still some issues. I was able to successfully call the DLL in the end. Using the X64 DLL resulted in an ERROR, but using the X86 DLL worked correctly without needing the ?c flag. My NSIS version is 3.10.

A x64 dll would require 64-bit NSIS.

Currently, you’re storing the input values in $0 and $1, but the line i(r0, r1).r2 may not properly assign the return value to $2
Change this line:
System::Call "$INSTDIR\NSISRegistryTool::Add(i, i) i(r0, r1).r2"

By:
System::Call "$INSTDIR\NSISRegistryTool::Add(i $0, i $1) i .r2"


https://nsis-dev.github.io/NSIS-Forums/html/t-309400.html


I tried your code, but $2 is still empty. I tested the DLL with a C++ project, and the DLL is fine
